# Integrate Salesforce with Active Campaign

Tags: apex, integration, callout

I want to integrate salesforce with ActiveCampighn using the Api key and Url of ActiveCampighn through Http Post method. I want to create a contact from Salesforce to Active campaign. I tried with the below code snippet and got 200(Success) status. But the contact is not available in Active Campaign.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('http://navsoft12350.activehosted.com/admin/api.php?api_action=contact_add');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'key={!$Credential.Password}');
string body = ' "contact": [ ' +
' { ' +
' "id": 12, ' +
' "email": "jsmith@example.com", ' +
' "firstName": "John", ' +
' "lastName": "smith", ' +
' "p[123]": "123", ' +
' "phone": 122222222' +
' }' +
' ]';
req.setBody(body);
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Kindly provide me any feasible solution of this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Parameters should be URL encoded. They don't accept any other input formats like JSON.

https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=contact_add

[image: See the image]

Here is an example of add contact in active campaign from Salesforce Apex

```
String key = 'Get FROM https://{{Host}}.activehosted.com/app/settings/developer';

    String authUrl = 'https://{{Host}.api-us1.com/admin/api.php?api_action=contact_add&api_key='+key;
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(authUrl);
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    String payload = 'email='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('test@example.com','UTF-8')+'&FirstName='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('FirstName','UTF-8')+'&last_name='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('last_name','UTF-8')+'&customer_acct_name='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('Acme, Inc.','UTF-8');
    System.debug(payload);

    request.setBody(payload);
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    } else {
        System.debug(response.getBody());
    }
```

Comment: !!Thank you very much, sir. It's working.